# Description of signals in Laptop Fans

Tags: fan

My laptop has this fan, which I want to replace. But before blindly replacing it and make it work I am curious to know what all signals are associated the four wires: Black, Pink, Yellow & Red. 
I could not find a technical specification for this model ([Asus BSB04505HA Fan](http://cyberwala.com/asus/1422-asus-bsb04505ha-fan.html)).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PC fans have standardised pinouts, so this shouldn't be a concern for replacement. If you are curious, there are [site](http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Motherboard_%28CPU%29_4_Pin_Fan)s which show which cable is which.

Comment: On the sticker on the fan DC05V is mention, Does that mean 5v input supply?

Comment: It says "5v" on the sticker on the fan doesn't it?

Comment: The picture above shows 5V, but in real fan which I am having DC05V is mentioned

Comment: @gpuguy The leading zero is just that: a leading zero. It is still 5V DC.